# GuzzleHttp Stream object to utf-8 encoded HTML?

Tags: php, guzzle

We have a client for a file system with method open() which returns \GuzzleHttp\Stream\Stream object. I have a pdf file to be read from the file system and therefore I am using open() method to get the output as Guzzle stream object.

I got to merge this pdf file with other pdfs which are being created using mpdf. I could not do that as the merge function(which is using FPDI) could not read xref-Data.

Is there any way that I can convert/manipulate GuzzleHttp stream object to a proper format to make the pdf parser be able to read it?

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use the getContents method of the Guzzle Stream object: http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/psr7.html?highlight=stream#streams. It returns a string representation of the data.

Comment: Is there a way that I can use the string representation of the data to convert to a format which the mpdf object would be able to read so that I can merge with other mpdf objects created.

Comment: Well I dont have experience with mpdf. You can another pdf merge library such as pdfmerger (https://pdfmerger.codeplex.com/) or libmergepdf (https://github.com/hanneskod/libmergepdf)